# Difference between "ignite" and "kindle"

Tags: difference, synonyms

Can't grasp the difference and the use cases of these 2 words. They both seem to mean something close to "set on fire", but what is the exact meaning, and are their use cases the same?

Can one *ignite a candle*, or *kindle a candle*?

The second sounds somewhat awkward to me and I haven't heard anyone using it.
The usage examples are welcome.

Comment: The actual definitions are more detailed, and should be added to your question along with what issue you cannot resolve.

Comment: @apsillers I agree that this question should not be closed, but it is always helpful to know what definitions the OP is working from.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't do either; I *light* a candle.

*Kindle* is a slow process, like when you're starting a fire in a fireplace. *Kindling* is little bits of wood or other material that you feed to the fire to get it going. Personally, it sounds weird to me if you're not talking about something like a wood fire.

*Ignite* is quick.  If lightning hits something and sets it on fire, it was ignited, not kindled. You can ignite gas, but not kindle it.

Both of these words have metaphorical uses which similarly are different in the implied speed of the action. Someone's work might *kindle interest* in a subject while a controversial comment by a politician *ignites debate*.

Comment: I think the explanation of kindle as slow and ignite as quick is very good.

Comment: Absolutely. Noting the [change in usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=kindle+a+fire%2Clight+a+fire&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ckindle%20a%20fire%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clight%20a%20fire%3B%2Cc0) over the past couple of centuries, I think the easiest way for learners to approach this one is to simply ignore ***kindle*** completely. It's not exactly "archaic", but few people use it these days. For most purposes, ***ignite*** is "formal, technical", whereas ***light*** is just a "normal, everyday" word.

Comment: TBH, the only thing I can think of that you *kindle* (other than a fire) is a romance.
In addition, *kindle* as a verb is more about providing fuel to support and encourage ignition; it's not synonymous with *ignite*.

Comment: Excellent answer. I love that you pointed out that neither option is as commonly used as to light.

Comment: Kindling is material used in a specific step in the process of building a fire. It goes spark (or embers) -> tinder -> kindling -> wood (or whatever fuel). Kindling is also the act you do to go from a spark to an open flame.

Answer (score 3):

Your feeling about this one is correct. You can't kindle a candle. I think it is important to know that the word 'kindling' means very small pieces of wood or material that catches fire easily, so kindle is more appropriately used where you are focusing on that process of adding a spark to something flammable, and are expecting that initial spark to grow into something larger. That isn't really what happens with a candle, where you are merely burning a wick and the initial flame is usually as large as the fire will ever become.

Kindle can be used as a metaphor, too, for something small that grows into something larger. If you think of Amazon's e-reader, for example, it is marketed as a small device that opens up an entire library of books for you - it was really a brilliant use of the word 'kindle' as a metaphor, whatever you think of the merits of the device.

Answer (score 0):

Ignite to my understanding means something gets on in an instant. Kindle to me means something gets on in a slow process.

Comment: You can improve your answer by citing a dictionary.

Answer (score -3):

To ignite is to 'Start the fire'
To kindle is to 'Keep the fire going'

Comment: I think this is completely wrong. To the extent that ***kindle*** has any direct implications for the ***start/maintain*** distinction, it very definitely describes ***starting*** a fire, rather than keeping it going.

Comment: Hi Edd - I agree with @FumbleFingers that kindle is starting a fire, not keeping it going (I would call that stoking the fire). Do you have any references that might support your interpretation?

Comment: @ColleenV: The nearest definition is probably OED 4c: *To spread like fire,* which is specifically identified as ***Obs. rare.*** This answer is just plain *wrong*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree, but this is a first post and I'm trying to be a little gentler with new users. It's possible there's an incorrect reference out there that led Edd down the wrong path.

Comment: @ColleenV: As I understand it, the purpose of the site is to provide a permanent record of good answers to good questions, not to tolerate/encourage *bad/incorrect* answers by failing to downvote for fear of seeming unwelcoming to new users. Imho this answer needs to be *deleted*, not "encouraged to cite a supporting reference" (which we can be quite sure is unreliable anyway! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers My comment might have been gentler, but I did vote to delete. I just didn't want to do that without some sort of guidance on how to write a better answer the next time.

Comment: @Fumble - I appreciate Colleen's approach. As a moderator who sees many of these answers flagged, I think the gentler approach is a good one for brand new users, in that it gives these user time to mull over the advice and hopefully improve the answer. Your admonishment about "not tolerating bad answers" came a mere 30 minutes after this user's first post! Not exactly something that will encourage the user to come back and learn how things work.

Comment: Frankly, I think the dictionaries I've seen here are getting it wrong, and poster is right. As I have always used the word and heard it used in the last five decades, kindle *does* imply maintaining or building a larger fire from a small one, not the actual act of ignition. My own cursory search in COCA seems pretty split, and a lot of uses are ambiguous (i.e., "I'll kindle a fire in the morning." could have either implication).

Comment: @LeeDanielCrocker maybe the issue is simply a misunderstanding about "keep the fire going" that could be cleared up with more explanation. Thinking about it, I might use a flint and steel to ignite my kindling, and the burning kindling to kindle my campfire. I see that as two different "fires" though - the fire I used to kindle the campfire and the campfire itself. The campfire is started by the kindling and not maintained by it in my mind.

Comment: @ColleenV That sounds mostly right. As someone who's built hundreds or maybe thousands of campfires, you're kindling the fire until it will go on its own without your continued attention (beyond throwing on some more fuel now and then).